# prove limit of ratio of log of power series to x is 1

Tags: limits

the proof for $\lim_{{x}\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln\left(1+x\right)}{x}$ = 1 can be derived immediately from $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} (1+x)^\frac1x = e$

I was asked to whether the following limit, extending the series in ln above from 2 to n+1 terms, is true:

$\lim_{{x}\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln\left(1+x+x^{2}+x^{3}+x^{4}+x^{5}+...+x^n\right)}{x}$ = 1

at the first look, it apparently is.
The mathematical induction method does not seem to be applicable here.
Does someone know a mehtod to prove it?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: What have you tried ? Where are your stuck ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For small x, use the approximation ln (1+x) = x

Note that x dominates higher powers of x for small x

Comment: This is a Goldilocks Answer: not too much info, not too little, but just the perfect amount of information, particularly when little to no effort is shown by the asker.  Nice answer +1

Comment: thank you. the hint is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\lim_{{x}\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln\left(1+x+x^{2}+x^{3}+x^{4}+x^{5}+...+x^n\right)}{x}    = \lim_{{x}\rightarrow 0}\frac{\left(x+x^{2}+x^{3}+x^{4}+x^{5}+...+x^n\right)}{x}$

Comment: thanks all for the tips